# The maximum length of the search box is too low

Tags: feature-request, search

I wanted to search for
`[python] [windows] [or] [http] [or] [http-requests] [or] [threading] [or] [multiprocessing] [or] [subprocess] [or] [python-requests] [or] [urlib3] [or] [pip] [or] [virtualenv] [or] [gevent] [or] [apscheduler] -[django] -[cherrypy] -[webpy] -[web2py] -[werkzeug] -[flask] -[pyramid] -[pyside] -[pyqt]`

but the resulting search string was truncated to

`[python] [windows] [or] [http] [or] [http-requests] [or] [threading] [or] [multiprocessing] [or] [subprocess] [or] [python-requests] [or] [u`

which is 140 characters long.

Is 140 the maximum length of the search box? If so I suggest to increase it. I guess it should be set so that maximum length of url supported by major browsers is not exceeded (the search string is part of url later on).

Comment: The team has an "all searches must be tweetable" business rule so that Internet social media users can facebook, tumbl and instagrammophone their Stack Exchanging behaviors for better leveraging PageRank and SEO, synergizing click-throughs and eyeballs. AdSense analytics projected quarterly earnings PE ratios.

Comment: Duuuuuuuuuuude.